# TSQL and case when with multiple whens?

Tags: t-sql, case-when

I have several conditions and the result for those should be the same. I searched the net and found stuff like this:

```
CASE ProductLine
     WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
     WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
     WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
     WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
     ELSE 'Not for sale'
  END
```

That's nice, but not what I need, for me its more like R,M,T and S all have the same result and A,B,C,D for example don't have. How would I do this? I cant connect with OR, or at least I did not manage to :). Something like this maybe?

```
CASE ProductLine
     WHEN 'R' OR 'M' OR ... THEN 'Road'
     ELSE 'Not for sale'
  END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change to a ["searched" CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). You have a "simple" CASE expression above

```
CASE
   WHEN  ProductLine IN ('R', 'M', ...) THEN 'Road'
   ELSE 'Not for sale'
END
```

From the MSDN link above:

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 

Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Comment: Nice! BTW, Why OR expression is not boolean expression is such case

Comment: @sll: SQL Server doesn't support boolean expression